# Updating data on child components from a parent component in Vue 3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, knockout.js, vuejs3

I'm migrating an application from KnockoutJS to VueJS. I'm having difficulty translating a template to a component. It's similar to a tab structure where only 1 item can be active which was controlled using an observable called isActive that I've changed to a ref. When a user clicks on an item I want to loop through the child components in a list on the parent and set the isActive value to false before setting isActive on the clicked item to true.

I have been able to update the clicked item's isActive value but I can't see the isActive ref values on the parent. How can I get the child components and their data from the parent?

I have an example of what the code looks like here. [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/magical-dream-d5k4z7?file=/src/components/selection/SelectionMenuItem.vue)

Comment: you ask about how passing data from child to parent ?

Comment: Not really. I'm using props to pass data from a parent to a child. The issue I'm having is I'm triggering an event on the child that is caught by the parent. I'd like to update refs on all the children that this event has occurred. Is there a way to change a ref on the child component from the parent? I know that I can pass a ref in the props from the parent. What I want is to create the ref in the setup of the child component. Is this possible?

Comment: I've added a more simplified example of what I'm trying to do. What I'd like to do in the deactivateAllChildren function the ParentComponent.vue file is to update all the children. Is this possible with the ref being defined in ChildComponent? Does isActive need to be passed into ChildComponent props as a ref? https://codesandbox.io/s/simplified-children-example-tqkoxl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `ref` to access the child component in the parent:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <child-component ref="mychild" />
    </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    mounted() {
        // this.$refs.mychild will be the instance of the child component.
        // You can access all of its data and methods
    }
}
</script>
```

Similarly, in the child component you may access the parent component using `$parent`. This isn't particularly recommended though as it couples the child component to the parent (meaning, it won't really work properly without it, and the goal should usually be to create agnostic components that can be reused anywhere), and usually there will be a better solution possible using props and emitting events.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I ran into some issues because I was using the Composition API and couldn't see this.$refs in the onMounted callback. I had tried this in the past but ran into issues using ref templates with v-for. On further investigation there is an open bug related to this on GitHub https://github.com/vuejs/core/issues/5525

Comment: Once I found this I was able to create a working example https://codesandbox.io/s/stock-overflow-children-question-solution-tl6iuh

Answer (score 0):

If you console out `menuItem.isActive.value`  in our `changeSelectionWizardView` function you will find your isActive reactive value.

But as I can see from your code you pass a plain/unreactive object as a props to your `SelectionMenuItem` components. So when you update the isActive value in the parent component the child will not get the change.

One possible solution is, make the menuItems a reactive data. Then pass the reactive menuItem as a props to the child components. And after each `change` emit event call you just update the menuItems isActive value and then the props will reactively pass the latest updated data to the child components.

I have made some changes in your code, Now I think it's working like what you mentioned in your question above.Here is the [link](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-banach-0giqp0?file=/src/components/selection/SelectionMenuItem.vue)

Lastly, one small suggestion, try to use either option API or composition API, don't use both of them at the same time, It makes your code debugging harder.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The behaviour is correct but I was wondering if there is a way to see the code on the child from the patent. I've setup another example where I've moved the MenuItem into it's own JS file and this works the way I want but it feels wrong to separate the MenuItem from the Vue component where it will be used. Is it possible to update a ref that exists on the child component only from the parent? https://codesandbox.io/s/so-classes-example-nqe2td

Comment: I've added a simplified version of the code here https://codesandbox.io/s/simplified-children-example-tqkoxl

Comment: Yes It is possible to update a ref that exists on the child component only from the parent and you have already done it using the `clicked` emits with `activateChild()`, I mean you update the child isActive  value from the parent component. Now I think the problem is how to update all the child compoennt's ref value, whenever any of the child component is clicked. For this I have two solution one is make the whole children array reactive data and listen the changes another one is use a `activeChildIdx` variable as ref value pass it to children as props and watch the props from child component.

Comment: [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/simplified-children-example-forked-tfpl4m?file=/src/components/ParentComponent.vue:702-716) Here I have implemented the 2nd solution. I used a `activeChildIdx` ref value in parent component and pass it to the child as a props. In child components I use a watcher and watch the change of `activeChildIdx` whenever any changes occur I call the `deactivateAllChildren()` functino using the `deactive` emits

Comment: This is a good suggestion. However, the ref solution mentioned by Brother Woodrow was closer to what I was looking for. Thanks for all the help.